# Instance was not declared in main function

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I have problem with creating instance. This is really trivial code and always works fine but when I started using MinGW compiler for C++11, this errors occurred.

main.cpp:16:35: error: 'myObjekt' was not declared in this scope

main.cpp:16:50: error: expected type-specifier main.cpp:16:50: error:

expected ';' main.cpp:20:12: error: type '' argument given

to 'delete', expected pointer

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Objekt.h"

    int main(int argc, char** argv){

        std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;

        Colonisation::Objekt::Objekt* myObjekt = new Colonisation::Objekt::Objekt(5,4);
        std::cout << myObjekt->getXPosition() << std::endl;
        std::cout << myObjekt->getYPosition() << std::endl;

        delete myObjekt;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The error messages mention lines 16 and 20, but your code has only 15 lines.

Comment: Are you sure it's `Colonisation::Objekt::Objekt` and not just `Colonisation::Objekt`?

Comment: @jogojapan Other lines are comments

Comment: @KerrekSB Colonisation is namespace, Objekt is class name and Object is constructor

Comment: @MartinKravec (reply to your reply to KerrekSB) In that case Kerrek is right, and it should be `Colonisation::Objekt`. No need (and in fact a mistake) to mention the constructor explicitly (the constructor always has the same name as the class).

Comment: @MartinKravec (reply to your reply to my first comment). It generally makes it hard for anyone to answer your questions if the line numbers in the error message don't match the code you provide and there are no comments in the code explaining what lines the errors refer to.

Comment: @MartinKravec: ... and KerrekSB correctly pointed out that repeating the type is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answers, solution is
`Colonisation::Objekt* myObjekt = new Colonisation::Objekt(5,4);`

Comment: When/where did this "always works fine"?

Answer (score 2):

So, the following should work as intended:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;

    Colonisation::Objekt* myObjekt = new Colonisation::Objekt(5,4);
    std::cout << myObjekt->getXPosition() << std::endl;
    std::cout << myObjekt->getYPosition() << std::endl;

    delete myObjekt;

    return 0;
}
```